Is it possible to solve an autonomous first-order differential equation by reciprocating the function?
Take $$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{6}(4-y)$$
An unorthodox approach is to reciprocate the function, i.e.,
$$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{6}{y(4-y)}$$ $$ x(y) = 6\int\frac{dy}{4y-y^2}$$ then to find the integral and then find the inverse of that function to find $y(x)$. I tried it but my solution had a slight discrepancy with the "actual" solution using orthodox practices. Did I make a mistake, or is this approach in general just wrong? And if it isn't wrong, why isn't it used more often?

Separation of variables should work , but this is also a Bernoulli differential equation where you can use the substitution $u=y^{-1}$ if you would like, which may give a neater solution more quickly.

This is perfectly fine.

On the search bar type switch variables  for my user name. There are 88 results.

Can you solve this DE this way? Yes! In addition to being autonomous, this is a separable differential equation and so you can solve it this way.
However, when you get to second-order and higher autonomous DEs, they may no longer be separable, so you need different approaches. This is true for a lot of what gets covered in courses on DEs - they will use a simple equation that might have multiple means of solving to demonstrate certain techniques that apply to different, more complicated equations.
It's hard to know whether you made a mistake in calculating the integral without seeing the solution you reached, however I can suggest a few things might have happened:

You may well have made a mistake with the integral.

The answer you got and the answer you saw elsewhere might be equivalent to each other. This is very common when there are multiple approaches to a DE, and sometimes you can transform one solution into the other to show that they're the same.



"The answer you got and the answer you saw elsewhere might be equivalent to each other."
This would be evident with constants, correct? As in, Ce^x = De^x iff. C=D. Or is it possible to have equivalent solutions that are not apparent just by equating the constants?

It's possible for the equivalence to not be immediately obvious. For example, $R \cos (x - x_0)$ and $A \cos x + B \sin x$ represent the same family of functions, but the relationship between $(R, x_0)$ and $(A, B)$ is not clear if you haven't done that transformation before. Or something like $\cos(\sin^{-1}(x)) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ can trip people up easily.
